# scipy ImportError when installing scikit-learn with pip on alpine

Tags: python, docker, scikit-learn, scipy, alpine-linux

I'm trying to build a docker image with certain python libraries starting from the `alpine` image. But `pip install scikit-learn` gives me an error:

```
ImportError: The `scipy` install you are using seems to be broken, (extension modules cannot be imported), please try reinstalling.
```

Complete error log at the end.

My `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM alpine
WORKDIR /root
COPY setup.sh /root/
RUN ./setup.sh
CMD ["/bin/sh"]
```

The `setup.sh` is as follows:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

set -ex
apk update
apk add --no-cache make cmake gcc g++ gfortran wget openblas-dev python3-dev py3-pip

pip install numpy
pip install pandas
pip install scipy
pip install scikit-learn
pip install requests
```

The specific versions that `pip` pulls are:

```
numpy-1.23.3
pandas-1.5.0
scipy-1.9.1
scikit-learn-1.1.2
```

When it gets to `pip install scikit-learn`, it runs for a bit and then gives me the error.
`pip install scipy` finishes without errors and even says:

```
Successfully built scipy
Installing collected packages: scipy
Successfully installed scipy-1.9.1
```

Here's the complete log:

```
Collecting scikit-learn
  Downloading scikit-learn-1.1.2.tar.gz (7.0 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 7.0/7.0 MB 24.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [47 lines of output]
      Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-xn0qm7wa/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/__init__.py", line 166, in <module>
          from scipy._lib._ccallback import LowLevelCallable
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-xn0qm7wa/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/_lib/_ccallback.py", line 1, in <module>
          from . import _ccallback_c
      ImportError: cannot import name '_ccallback_c' from 'scipy._lib' (/tmp/pip-build-env-xn0qm7wa/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/_lib/__init__.py)

      The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "setup.py", line 200, in check_package_status
          module = importlib.import_module(package)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-xn0qm7wa/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy/__init__.py", line 171, in <module>
          raise ImportError(msg) from e
      ImportError: The `scipy` install you are using seems to be broken, (extension modules cannot be imported), please try reinstalling.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 164, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-xn0qm7wa/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 174, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-xn0qm7wa/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 267, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-xn0qm7wa/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
          exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
        File "setup.py", line 329, in <module>
          setup_package()
        File "setup.py", line 305, in setup_package
          check_package_status("scipy", min_deps.SCIPY_MIN_VERSION)
        File "setup.py", line 227, in check_package_status
          raise ImportError(
      ImportError: scipy is not installed.
      scikit-learn requires scipy >= 1.3.2.
      Installation instructions are available on the scikit-learn website: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: There currently aren't any scipy `musllinux` wheels available for Alpine, so I'm surprised that you could pip install it. This will be why you get the `ImportError`, the `_ccallback_c` shared object is not usable (different libc). There is a plan for making `musllinux` wheels available, but requires `numpy` wheels for `musllinux` first.